# Creating command say embed on discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a discord.py robot and I want the say embed command and I want me to write it like that

```
R!sayembed title=hi description=hi
```

I have a code it just doesn't work the way I want

```
@bot.command()
async def sayembed(ctx, *, message):
embed = discord.Embed(
    title=message,
    description=message,
    colour=discord.Color.green()
    )

await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

please someone help me with that command

Comment: discord.py does not support kwargs, you're gonna have to do some regex by yourself to get it working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Łukasz Kwieciński said, discord.py does not support kwargs. I suggest you to try changing the way to call your function, it can get easier for you.

You could just call your function as:

```
R!sayembed "Here goes your title" "Here goes your description"
```

This would make your code as simple as just passing two string parameters to your function:

```py
@bot.command()
async def sayembed(ctx, title: str, description: str):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=title,
        description=description,
        colour=discord.Color.green()
        )

    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```